# PostgreSQL: getting all functions related to table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this function:

```
SELECT n.nspname AS schema_name
      ,p.proname AS function_name
      ,pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) AS args
      ,pg_get_functiondef(p.oid) AS func_def
FROM   (SELECT oid, * FROM pg_proc p WHERE NOT p.proisagg) p
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE  n.nspname !~~ 'pg_%'
AND    n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
AND    pg_get_functiondef(p.oid) ~ '\mTableName\M';
```

it gives me a list of functions that uses TableName. However it doesn't ignore notes. For example if in  `function A` there will be a line like:

```
-- select * from TableName
```

it will show `A` in the result even though its a note and `A` doesn't really uses `TableName`.

How can I make a query that does the same thing but ignore all notes?

Comment: You could add maybe some RegEx-search pattern .. something like --[._+=[:alnum:] ]+TableName

Comment: I'm not a SQL guru, but my instinctive reaction is that this is either not possible, or so extremely complex that it's not worth doing.  You're much more likely better off just manually reviewing the results of the query you have.

Comment: in PostgreSQL each row of note must be with '--' unlike other languages where you can open a block of note with mark at start and in end.. so my instinct is to adjust query to ignore all lines starting with '--' but i'm not sure if it's doable.

Comment: @John My succession ;)

Comment: Commented lines is not your only problem; just think of `EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM Table' || 'Name'`; you won't get a reliable list from function definitions.

Comment: this query is just for learning use.. it will not be implemented in real system. it's just for me to find out information i seek.

Answer (score 0):

You may find everything you need directly on this wiki page : https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pg_depend_display

There is all sorts of dependency views depending on you PostgreSQL version.